# Remove shadow from ActiveX Option Button in Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I was trying to emphasis the option button from activeX control when it is selected by user. I decided to show the shadow when it is selected and then hide the shadow when user selects other option button. The first process is working whereas the shadow cannot be removed even though I select other button. My VBA code is shown below:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()

OptionButton1.Shadow = False

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
OptionButton1.Shadow = True

Else
OptionButton1.Shadow = False

End If

End Sub
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: do you have code in the other button to remove the shadow from OptionButton1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to create one sub which needs to be called from all the option buttons that you have. This common sub will simply remove the shadow from all option buttons. Here I am taking the example of 3 option buttons.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    RemoveShadow

    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then _
    OptionButton1.Shadow = True
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    RemoveShadow

    If OptionButton2.Value = True Then _
    OptionButton2.Shadow = True
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    RemoveShadow

    If OptionButton3.Value = True Then _
    OptionButton3.Shadow = True
End Sub

Sub RemoveShadow()
    Dim objOpt As OLEObject

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each objOpt In .OLEObjects
            If TypeName(objOpt.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
                objOpt.Shadow = False
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

In case of FORMS buttons you can use

```
Sub RemoveFormsButtonShadows()
     'A.Leine 21/10/2015
     For Each Button In ActiveSheet.Shapes
         Button.Select
         Selection.ShapeRange.Shadow.Visible = False
     Next Button
End Sub
```